# Managing multiple DBs and servers with central or local processes?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

In my previous job, I had to manage some DBs (~500) installed on some servers (~20). Everything on SQLServer.

For basic tasks such as backups, archives or monitoring, I used to have a process installed on a **central** server which knows where is everything and what to do on each DB or server. So, a generic SSIS package, some configuration tables, a couple of SQLServer jobs, and we loop, apply scripts, and **pull** results and logs to this central DB server.

Everything was going well and I get used to that kind of design. And also learnt the good and the bad (ex: pro = only one process easy to configure ; con = it's a kind of spof).

Now, in my new company, I am facing the opposite: each server has its own **local** jobs and scripts, and **pushes** the results to a central DB server (using linked servers).
First, I thought it was not a very reliable way of doing things (if one task is completely failing, nobody knows / harder versioning / etc...). But actually, it seems to work well for years.

So I would like to have a better point of view than "*I'm not used to that so it's bad*".

**What could be the pros and cons of each approach ?** (in a SQLServer environment, version 2008 and more).

Answer (score 0):

In the environment I managed for about a decade, backups were handled by local jobs, but we did have a couple of monitoring jobs (daily login records for audit purposes, and daily report on failed jobs) that was centralized.

So, here's what I can think of:

**Centralized job "hub"**

PROS:

- Same approach applied to all servers.
- Easy to change process for all servers in the environment.
- Easy to monitor entire environment.

CONS:

- One point of failure - If the hub fails, nothing gets backed up, etc.
- Likely implemented with one account with admin access to all servers - if that's compromised, everything is.
- "One size fits all" approach to all tasks may not be appropriate, in some cases (server-specific jobs may limit when you want to do full backups, for example; if all full backups are run from a single job, it becomes more difficult to accommodate specific time frames for particular servers).
- You can presumably run certain unique jobs from that single server, but beyond a certain point it gets confusing as to which jobs hit which servers.
- Harder to check status of a single server (unless that data is retained in a central table, in which case it may actually be easier).

**Server maintenance jobs run locally, reported to hub**

PROS:

- Jobs can be configured as is best for that server.
- One server can fail with no impact to the others.
- Can use accounts that do not need access to all servers.
- Easier to confirm activity for a single server - check the Job Activity Monitor for the server, all jobs are there.

CONS:

- Failure of one server to report job status to hub server may not be noticed (harder to notice something that isn't there than something that is).
- Jobs *have* to be set up one each server, or backups, etc. won't happen.
- May be harder to spot trends affecting multiple servers.
- Jobs may not be configured in a consistent way (even if the same person configures all the servers).

Many of the cons can be overcome if you've still got a central server that receives/collects data on jobs across all servers. As I said, that's the environment I worked in for several years, and it worked well for us.